# How to replace old Linksys router with a new Linksys router and configure the new one?

Tags: networking

I'm not a network admin but i've a basic understanding in networks. We are using a lease line for internet in our office and we are using Linksys router to route it to Vonage (VoIP) and Netgear.

Our Linksys started troubling and we have decided to replace it with a new one (same model WRT320N). The old linksys is already 'congifured' for the internet connection to work. Now how to configure the new router to get the internet connectivity?

I'm not able to connect to the new router using 192.168.1.1. Or am i missing something?

Thank you.

NLV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a separate machine, with its interface configured for DHCP. Plug this machine exclusively into the new router and request a new DHCP assignment. Use your operating system's network interface information tool to discover the default gateway assigned to the interface, and connect to this address via HTTP using a browser.

Comment: I tried to connect the old router directly to my machine and did a 192.168.1.1. Why am i not able to connect to it? If the ip of the router is different how to identify that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm under the impression that linksys used 192.168.0.1 for routers. You can check with the ipconfig command on cmd.exe - default gateway will be your router's ip address